# antiforgerytoken in ajax post with json object ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, json, ajax, antiforgerytoken

I have a problem with posting converted json object to controller using `antiforgerytoken`. Passed argument `questionnaireViewModel` is null. 
I've tried to add to ajax:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

or

```
headers: { '__RequestVerificationToken': token },
```

but nothing have changed. Could you help me?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostQuestionnaire", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryQuestionnaireForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult PostQuestionnaire(QuestionnaireViewModel questionnaireViewModel)
    { ... }

$('#submitBtn').on('click', function () {

   var questionnaireVM = JSON.stringify({
    'questionnaireViewModel': {
        'QuestionnaireId': $('#QuestionnaireId').val(),
        'Revision': $('#Revision').val(),
        'IPAddress': '',        
    }
});

var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryQuestionnaireForm');
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./PostQuestionnaire",
    data: { 
            __RequestVerificationToken: token, 
            questionnaireVM 
        },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            console.log("success");

        } else {
            console.log("fail");
        }
    },
    error: function (request) {
            console.log("error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to stringify your data in POST methods, just make a json object:

```
let d = {
    'QuestionnaireId': $('#QuestionnaireId').val(),
    'Revision': $('#Revision').val(),
    'IPAddress': '',        
}
```

and replace the data part in your Ajax call with the following code:

```
data: { 
        __RequestVerificationToken: token, 
        questionnaireViewModel: d
    },
```

Comment: so please mark it as answer